# Contains method not returning true when the mouse is in Rectangle

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, mouseevent

I have a grid of painted rectangle objects. I've added a `MouseAdapter` to a `JPanel`. In my MouseDragged method, I am trying to listen to the JPanel to see if it has been clicked and dragged, upon which I will find out whether the mouse reticle is in a certain rectangle, then perform something on that certain rectangle which is in a list. I don't know why the contains method is not working. PLEASE HELP

**I do make an initial mainPanel in a constructor:**

```
public UI()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                initList.add(new PathRectangle(i*49, j*49, 49, 49));
            }
        }
        
        mainPanel = new MainPanel(10, 10, initList);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
}
```

**There is more by have omitted it because it is irrelevant.**

**Main suspect:**

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                    System.out.println("Rectangle clicked");
                    for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if(paintedRectangles.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
                        {
                            //This will have to change in the future just testing it right now
                            paintedRectangles.get(i).setRecVal(PathRectangle.recType.WALL);
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
```

**JPanel Class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

private ArrayList<PathRectangle> paintedRectangles = new ArrayList<>();

int rows = 0, cols = 0;
int rectLenWidSize;


public MainPanel(int mRows, int mCols, ArrayList<PathRectangle> mPathRectangles) 
{
    rows = mRows;
    cols = mCols;
    paintedRectangles = mPathRectangles;

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
       
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(paintedRectangles.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
                    {
                        //This will have to change in the future just testing it right now
                        paintedRectangles.get(i).setRecVal(PathRectangle.recType.WALL);
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
        {
                System.out.println("Rectangle clicked");
                for(int i = 0; i < paintedRectangles.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(paintedRectangles.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
                    {
                        //This will have to change in the future just testing it right now
                        paintedRectangles.get(i).setRecVal(PathRectangle.recType.WALL);
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
        }
    });

    
    
    rectLenWidSize = (int) (-13.2306 * (Math.log(0.0023*((mRows + mCols) / 2))));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            
            switch(paintedRectangles.get(i).getRecVal())
            {
                case UNDECLARED:
                g.drawRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case WALL:
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j, rectLenWidSize*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case STARTNODE:
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;

                case ENDNODE:
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(i*rectLenWidSize, j*rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize, rectLenWidSize);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Rectangle Class:**

```
import  java.awt.*;

public class PathRectangle extends Rectangle
{

    private recType recVal = recType.UNDECLARED;

    //double pythHeurVal, manhattanHeurVal;

    public PathRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public enum recType{WALL, STARTNODE, ENDNODE, UNDECLARED}

    public recType getRecVal() {
        return this.recVal;
    }

    public void setRecVal(recType wall) {
        this.recVal = wall;
    }


}
```

Comment: . Did you debug the code by adding a System.out.println(...) statement to display the value of the mouse point and the bounds of each rectangle so see if  the point is contained in the rectangle?

Comment: You are not using `paintedRectangles` when you do your painting.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @camickr Yes I have tried that

Comment: @VGR Yes, I am not using paintedRectangles, because I am using the ArrayList just as a way for me to specify the individual properties of each Rectangle. I also loop through paintedRectangles to find out which rectangle the user clicked on.

Comment: You might want to consider making your mouse drag detection and your painting use the same data.  It would be a good way to visually confirm that you’re checking what you think you’re checking in your mouse listener.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *Yes I have tried that* - so where is the output? Do a simple test with a single rectangle so it is easy to verify that the point is in the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: @camickr I tried this and it worked as expected. When I clicked on the single rectangle it turned into the appropriate color and the point that I printed was inside the rectangle.